# SQL Server parse array of XML Nodes using XMLQUERY

Tags: arrays, sql-server, xmlnode, qxmlquery

I am trying to parse an XML Array of nodes, which is a nvarchar(max) column converted to XML, and I've searched using google and searched stackoverflow, but I'm not finding any examples that may help me out with this.

What I have is an XML value stored as nvarchar(max) with the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfCmnStatusRuleOverride xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cmnStatusRuleOverride xsi:type="cmnCoveredByOverride">
        <Start>2020-05-28T17:00:00</Start>
        <End>2020-05-29T07:00:00</End>
        <SuspendExpiration>0001-01-01T00:00:00</SuspendExpiration>
        <subID>103</subID>
        <listID>4016</listID>
        <Description>Jane Doe</Description>
    </cmnStatusRuleOverride>
    <cmnStatusRuleOverride xsi:type="cmnCoveredByOverride">
        <Start>2020-05-26T17:00:00</Start>
        <End>2020-05-28T07:00:00</End>
        <SuspendExpiration>0001-01-01T00:00:00</SuspendExpiration>
        <subID>103</subID>
        <listID>4014</listID>
        <Description>Joe Blow</Description>
    </cmnStatusRuleOverride>
    <cmnStatusRuleOverride xsi:type="cmnCoveredByOverride">
        <Start>2020-05-25T17:00:00</Start>
        <End>2020-05-26T07:00:00</End>
        <SuspendExpiration>0001-01-01T00:00:00</SuspendExpiration>
        <subID>103</subID>
        <listID>4016</listID>
        <Description>Jane Doe</Description>
    </cmnStatusRuleOverride>
</ArrayOfCmnStatusRuleOverride>
```

I'm using the following SQL to parse the content, which is close to what I need, but the cross applies are causing me problems

```
declare @Status xml, @Override nvarchar(100),@ORStart nvarchar(50), @OREnd nvarchar(50)
set @Status = 
(select b.Overrides from Database.dbo.Descriptions as a
inner join Database.dbo.Listings as b on a.listID = b.listId
inner join Database.dbo.Clients as c on b.subId = c.subId and cast(c.ClientNumber as nvarchar) = '2195956693'
--cross apply @Status.nodes('/ArrayOfCmnStatusRuleOverride/cmnStatusRuleOverride/Description') as T(Loc)
where a.Description = 'Jack Sprat')

select T.OVR.query('.') 'Override'--, T1.STT.query('.') 'Start'--, T2.ENND.query('.') 'End'
from Database.dbo.Descriptions as a
inner join Database.dbo.Listings as b on a.listID = b.listId
inner join Database.dbo.Clients as c on b.subId = c.subId and cast(c.ClientNumber as nvarchar) = '9876543210'
cross apply @Status.nodes('/ArrayOfCmnStatusRuleOverride/cmnStatusRuleOverride/Description') as T(OVR)
--cross apply T.OVR.nodes('/ArrayOfCmnStatusRuleOverride/cmnStatusRuleOverride/Start') as T1(STT)
--cross apply T.OVR.nodes('/ArrayOfCmnStatusRuleOverride/cmnStatusRuleOverride/End') as T2(ENND)
where a.Description = 'Jack Sprat'
```

With the second and third xml queries commented out, I get 3 results, as I would expect.

1. Jane Doe
2. Joe Blow
3. Jane Doe

If I uncomment the second query, then I get 9 results as follows

```
    Override        Start
```

1. Jane Doe 2020-05-28T17:00:00
2. Jane Doe 2020-05-26T17:00:00
3. Jane Doe 2020-05-25T17:00:00
4. Joe Blow 2020-05-28T17:00:00
5. Joe Blow 2020-05-26T17:00:00
6. Joe Blow 2020-05-25T17:00:00
7. Jane Doe 2020-05-28T17:00:00
8. Jane Doe 2020-05-26T17:00:00
9. Jane Doe 2020-05-25T17:00:00

And, of course, if I uncomment the third query, I get 27 rows.  Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?  I've worked with this since yesterday morning trying to figure this out, and so close, yet so far away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
select T.OVR.query('./Description') 'Override', 
T.OVR.query('./Start') 'Start', 
T.OVR.query('./End') 'End'
from Database.dbo.Descriptions as a
inner join Database.dbo.Listings as b on a.listID = b.listId
inner join Database.dbo.Clients as c on b.subId = c.subId and cast(c.ClientNumber as nvarchar) = '9876543210'
cross apply @Status.nodes('/ArrayOfCmnStatusRuleOverride/cmnStatusRuleOverride') as T(OVR)
where a.Description = 'Jack Sprat'
```